# UIWebview/WKWebivew WebP support

Tags: ios, swift, webp

I am trying to support loading html with `webp` image links served up to me from an API.  Here is a fake sample of html:

```
let theBody = "<img src=\"https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery3/2_webp_ll.webp\">"
webView.loadHTMLString(theBody, baseURL: nil)
```

However, this just load a placeholder:

[image]

Sometimes I might even get image strings with a `.png` format but the webview's GET request shows the content type is still `webp`

how can I get the `UIWebView`/`WKWebView` to support webp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIWebView` and `WKWebView` (and for that matter Safari and `SFSafariViewController`) do not support webp.

https://caniuse.com/#search=webp

There's nothing you can do about this until Apple adds support.

Comment: WebP support added in [Safari 14](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-14-release-notes) (**iOS 14 and higher**)